# Create set of equations by replacing constant values

Tags: equation-solving

Say I have an equation:

```
eq = ax + by + c == 0
```

and I want to run `NSolve` on a set of equations of this form, for example:

```
NSolve[{5x + 7y - 6, 9x - 2y + 3}]
```

How can I use the single definition of `eq` above to do this, by replacing `a`, `b` and `c` with the required values? It is ok to write it manually in NSolve for a simple example as above, but the real equation I will be doing this with has many more terms, and I will be solving a set of 8 equations!

Overall it'd be great if I could take a single equation like `eq` above, and then a list of the values that I want to be used (eg. a list of values for `a`, a list of values for `b` and a list of values for `c`) and then generate a list to pass to `NSolve`.

This is probably a fairly simple question, but I'm a beginner with Mathematica (although an experienced programmer in many other languages), so I'm not sure how to approach it. I suspect there may be a built-in function that will do this (or something like it) - is that the case?

Comment: There must be spaces between `a` and `x`, `b` and `c` defining eq. `eq = a x + b y + c == 0;` then better use `Solve` rather than `NSolve` : `Solve[eq /. {{a -> 5, b -> 7, c -> -3}, {a -> 9, b -> -2, c -> 3}}, {x, y}]`. `/.` is a shorthand for `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: Those lists of values of `a` and `b`, when assembled into a list, form a *matrix* which you can pass directly to [LinearSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html) along with the list of `c` values. When you have more equations than variables, though, you need to use a least squares approach: look to [LeastSquares](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeastSquares.html) and its kin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way you input values (without actually replacing the parameter with a number) is as follows:

```
eq/.{a->1,b->2,c->3}
```

this will result in:

```
x+2y+3.
```

you can put this in a loop (or something more clever, I'm new to mathematica as well) and output your results into an array or whatever you like.

hope this was helpful. Good Luck!